# Revert a number to its original value in PHP

Tags: php, logic

I have a problem in reverting the original amount of a customer.

A customer can amortize its balance in 3 months.

So, if the balance is **1,100.00**

**1,100.00 / 3 = 366.666666667** rounded up to **366.67**

But then, he decided to cancel the amortization.

What I do is amortized amount * 3, which is:
**366.67 * 3 = 1,100.01**

Expected output should be **1,100.00**

Thanks!

Comment: you need to apply [ceil()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) or [floor()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php). As well as while using float/double values for calculations you cannot assure 100% correctness.... Also you can save original value somewhere so that it will be shown as it is in case of cancellation

Comment: Well, this is obviously a rounding problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is the original calculation, if you have `1,100.00` to pay and simply divide by 3 with rounding, your customer will actually pay `1,100.01`!

The usual solution is to compensate this difference in the last (or first) amount to pay:

- n-1 first payments: `total / n` -> for your example: 2 times `366.67`
- last payment: `total - sum of precedent payments` -> for your example: `1,100.00 - (2 * 366.67)` so `366.66` to pay

Like this the total paid will always be right, whatever you apply flooring or rounding, and you can reverse any time by adding each value.

Answer (score 0):

Save the original value `1,100.00` somewhere (database, variable, etc.) and when they cancel their amortization, set the display from the saved value instead of calculating it.